# Webkit Browsers (Chrome and Safari) don't like mailto?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, mailto

Below is my code:

```
    function email(from, to, subject, body){

    if(subject == "Website Feedback"){
        to = to + "; augustoandrew@gmail.com";
    }

    if(from == "Outlook" || from == "LiveDesk"){
        window.location="mailto:"+to+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+body;
    }else if(from == "Gmail"){
        window.location="https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0"+to+"&su"+subject+"&body"+body;
    }
}
```

^^ Javascript for the below HTML

```
    <div id="hiddenForm">
    <form>
        What do you use for your email? <select id="from">
                                            <option value="Outlook">Outlook (Desktop Mail)</option>
                                            <option value="Gmail">Gmail (Web Mail)</option>
                                            <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo (Web Mail)</option>
                                            <option value="Live">Windows Live (Web Mail)</option>
                                            <option value="LiveDesk">Windows Live (Desktop Mail)</option>
                                            <option value="AOL">AOL (Web Mail)</option>
                                        </select><br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        Subject:    <select id="subj">
                        <option value="General">General</option>
                        <option value="Appointment">Appointment</option>
                        <option value="Website Feedback">Website Feedback</option>
                    </select><br />
        <br />
        Body: <br /><textarea id="message"></textarea><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="email(this.form.from.value, 'bibbidy@judys.com', this.form.subj.value, this.form.message.value)" /> 
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is that in Internet Explorer and Firefox, this code works perfectly.  In Safari and Chrome, it won't work.  It basically just reloads the page, but nothing happens.  As you can see, its only set up to work with Outlook and Live (desktop version) using mailto. Gmail I'm not sure works yet.  If anyone can help me to know why the webkit browsers aren't recognizing this code, please do.

Comment: I'm not sure about browsers, but I know I don't like mailto links! SCNR

Comment: Please note this: Using `mailto` requires that the computer that the user is using has a mail client configured. Today many users use a web client and therefore it won't work. A much better solution is to send the form back to your server (using `method='post'` in the form-tag) and process the data there. It is also much faster since you don't have to wait for the mail to go through all the mail servers before if comes back to you.

Comment: Yeah i understand that.  For testing purposes and just for now I want to make sure that I can build the email from this.   Down the road when this becomes a server application I will take that into consideration and refactor my code accordingly.  For now though I am just testing it on my computer where I have a desktop client set up.

Comment: It's your decision, but my opinion is that you're wasting your time with methods that where obsoleted about 15 years ago. You can download a complete web-server with script- and database-capabilities in a [single package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMP_packages). With that you can write code that you can move to the real server when it's finished and you only have to edit a configuration file to get your application to use the right resources on the real server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try window.location.href='mailto:marco@h4kr.com'; ;)

works for chrome 12 ;) haven't tested it in safari :)

Comment: Just tested in Safari 5.0.5/OS X 10.6.7 and it worked as well.

Comment: hmm...this is very strange.  It is not working for me.  I changed my window.location to window.location.href, and that didn't work.  So i tried changing the string to a solid email not built by strings, that didnt work.  So i tried making the button to the mailto, that didnt work.  So i then changed the link that shows the hidden form. It used to be href="#" but now i gave it a mailto link.  THAT worked. I might have to play around with the hrefs and maybe make the send button an <a> tag instead.

Comment: woa.. just do the following with your form:
add onsubmit="return false" and then this should work for you.. that might be because your code is already working.. but every time you click on the button the form is submitted ;)

so <form onsubmit="return false">

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for great help I have done finally with some help from above code.

```
function mailURL(url)
{
  var mailto_link = 'mailto:'+'?subject='+document.title+'&body='+escape(url);

        if(getBrowser()=='mozilla'){
            // Mozilla FireFox Mail To Friend
            // Opens a new tab but also opens up Microsoft Office window with URL
            window.open(mailto_link,'emailWindow'); 
        }
        else if(getBrowser()=='ie'){
            // IE Favourite
            window.open(mailto_link,'emailWindow');
        }
        else if(getBrowser()=='opera'){
            // Opera
            return true;
        }           
        else if (getBrowser()=='safari'){ // safari
            window.location.href=mailto_link;
            //alert('mail to safari');
        }
        else if(getBrowser()=='chrome'){
            window.location.href=mailto_link; 
            //alert('mail to chrome'); 
        }                       
  }

function getBrowser(){
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(userAgent);
        $.browser.safari= /webkit/.test(userAgent);
        $.browser.opera=/opera/.test(userAgent);
        $.browser.msie=/msie/.test( userAgent ) && !/opera/.test( userAgent );
        $.browser.mozilla= /mozilla/.test( userAgent ) && !/(compatible|webkit)/.test( userAgent ) || /firefox/.test(userAgent);

        if($.browser.chrome) return "chrome";
        if($.browser.mozilla) return "mozilla";
        if($.browser.opera) return "opera";
        if($.browser.safari) return "safari";
        if($.browser.msie) return "ie";

}
```